# Issue in Accessing FACEBOOK site in Domain network

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, group-policy, domain, website

In our Domain,We have setup firewall to prevent unwanted access to the websites. But a weird thing is even network administrators(whose IPs are not blocked by firewall) cannot access to facebook site.I have checked a few things.

- Facebook is not blocked by the antivirus on the local system
- No GPO to block facebook in the Domain.
- Some computers are not in the Domain. But they cannot access the site.
- **Even IPs' having full web access cannot access.(But they can access other Social sites)**
- **Changed the DNS IP to Google's PUBLIC DNS IP:** 8.8.4.4
  Nothing works.
  Access Facebook shows the following screen:
  ["Server not found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ59l.jpg)

Technically where is the issue?

**Note:I can access FB when I fully encrypt the connection**

Answer (score 0):

Turn-off your Firewall. If you can access Facebook when it's off, the the problem is in your Firewall. If not, then look somewhere else in the network where you made restrictions. You might have duplicate policies.

If it did work after you turned the Firewall off, then the issue is there. The Firewall rule was either configured incorrectly or the Firewall itself is "broken" and does not follow the rules instructed to it properly.